# From mothers to mammals

Tags: etymology

I was wondering what the relation is between mother and mammals. I know mammal refers to the mammalian glands which every mammal uses for the production of milk. Now, the word mammal is very similar to Mamma - Mam/Mom/Mum - Mother. 
I've read about the Proto Indo European origin of mother - but I can't find anything about the link between this and mammals...
Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: See [mammal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mammal) and [mother](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mother&allowed_in_frame=0)

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. *Mammal* is comes from the modern Latin word *Mammalia*, which comes from the Latin *mamma*, meaning "breast." [Mammal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mammal) is probably a cognate of [mamma](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mamma).